# passing grep into a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a file named email.txt like these one :

```
Subject:My test
From:my email <myemail@gmail.com>

this is third test
```

I want to take out only the email address in this file by using bash script.So i put this script in my bash script named myscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(myscript)

var1=$(awk 'NR==2' $file)

var2=$("$var1" | (grep -Eio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b'))

echo $var2
```

But I failed to run this script.When I run this command manually in bash i can obtain the email address:

```
echo $var1 | grep -Eio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b'
```

I need to put the email address to store in a variable so i can use it in other function.Can someone show me how to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $file` to make sure `myscript` really returns the contents from email.txt?

Comment: @flesk yup..i've already done that.The $file have the exact line and content that i want to grep and it can echo without problem

Comment: In case the `From:` line is not on line 2: `awk -F : '$1 == "From" {print $2; exit}' "$file"`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think this is an overly complicated way to go about things, but if you just want to get your script to work, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="email.txt"

var1=$(awk 'NR==2' $file)

var2=$(echo "$var1" | grep -Eio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b')

echo $var2
```

I'm not sure what `file=$(myscript)` was supposed to do, but on the next line you want a file name as argument to `awk`, so you should just assign `email.txt` as a string value to `file`, not execute a command called `myscript`. `$var1` isn't a command (it's just a line from your text file), so you have to `echo` it to give `grep` anything useful to work with. The additional parentheses around `grep` are redundant.

Comment: when using this solution it does not give me any error BUT it does not give me output either when i'm echoing $var2

Comment: @newbie.my: Added double quotes around `$var1`.

Comment: i've been so silly.your solution is working.Because i am using different variable in my machine so the variable name should be change.Anyway thanks for the code!

Answer (score 11):

What is happening is this:

```
var2=$("$var1" | (grep -Eio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b'))
       ^^^^^^^ Execute the program named (what is in variable var1).
```

You need to do something like this:

```
var2=$(echo "$var1" | grep -Eio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b')
```

or even

```
var2=$(awk 'NR==2' $file | grep -Eio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are very helpful flags for bash: -xv

The line with

```
var2=$("$var1" | (grep...
```

should be

```
var2=$(echo "$var1" | (grep...
```

Also my version of grep doesn't have -o flag.

And, as far as grep patterns are "greedy" even as the following code runs, it's output is not exactly what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
file=test.txt
var1=$(awk 'NR==2' $file)

var2=$(echo "$var1" | (grep -Ei '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}\b'))

echo $var2
```

Comment: i've already try you solution.But it is not working.And by the way my grep have -o flag.It is for show only matching part with the pattern

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bash parameter expansion`,

```
var2="${var1#*:}"
```

Comment: This is not command substitution, command substitution is $(command).  What you have shown is a form of parameter expansion (there are many).  You are removing the shortest string on the left ending in ':'

Answer (score 0):

There's a cruder way:

```
cat $file | grep @ | tr '<>' '\012\012' | grep @
```

That is, extract the line(s) with @ signs, turn the angle brackets into newlines, then grep again for anything left with an @ sign.

Refine as needed...